# Upload image as base64

Tags: upload, image-uploading

We develop a marketplace, mobile application, so the user can upload product images. Usually, we make a service to upload an image using multipart/form-data. But we saw that others upload images using base64.

What benefits has base64 upload over multipart/form-data upload?

Comment: Probably none. This may just be their process, base64 might be a result from getting data via canvas api or similiar. So their upload may include some preview or even edit function where the easiest result is the base64 encoded image.